# LogNotificationListener take a while on startup of Jboss

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

When I start my Jboss server (5.1), I have the following line in logs:

```
[LogNotificationListener] Adding notification listener for logging
mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server
org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@1bfefb[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
```

This line takes 30 seconds before to continue the startup.

I don't know what does this line (the code behind this line of course).

Why takes it a long time and what does it do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enable DEBUG logging and you will see what's going on. Add to startup parameters

```
-Djboss.server.log.threshold=DEBUG
```

and you will see it in:

```
jboss-as/server/${profile}/log/server.log
```

Or change configuration to see it in console. Config file is here:

```
jboss-as/server/${profile}/conf/jboss-log4j.xml
```

Comment: Ok, it adds many services and components during this time. Too bad it doesn't show it whitout debug.